# I am working with ASP.NET MVC. I tried to join 2 models into 1 viewModel. No error during debugging, but still can't get my out put in the view cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Employee Model

```
    namespace Company.Models 
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        
        public partial class Employee
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public Employee()
            {
                this.VehiculeArchivs = new HashSet<VehiculeArchiv>();
                this.CarInUses = new HashSet<CarInUses >();
            }
        
            public string EmployeeNr { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime EntranceDate { get; set; }
            public string Title{ get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string FirstName{ get; set; }
            public System.DateTime BOF{ get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage","CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<VehiculeArchiv> VehiculeArchivs { get; set; }
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage","CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<PKWInNutzung> CarInUses { get; set; }
            public virtual KeyBySecurtiyDepartment KeyBySecurtiyDepartment { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

KeySecurityDepartment Model

```
namespace Company.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class KeyBySecurityDepartment
    {
        public string EmployeeNr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IssueDate { get; set; }
        public bool Monday { get; set; }
        public bool Tuesday{ get; set; }
        public bool Wednesday{ get; set; }
        public bool Thursday{ get; set; }
        public bool Friday { get; set; }
        public bool Saturday { get; set; }
        public bool Sunday { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> StartTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool TransponterKey { get; set; }
        public bool 11Door { get; set; }
        public bool 111PostalBox { get; set; }
        public bool 1113MainGate { get; set; }
        public bool 116PersonalOffice { get; set; }
        public bool 117MainOffice { get; set; }
        public bool 118Halle { get; set; }
      public virtual Employee Employee{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view model:

```
namespace Company.ViewModels
{
    public class KeyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> employee{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<KeyBySecurityDepartment> KeyBySecurityDepartment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
namespace Company.Controllers
{
    public class KeyBySecurityDepartmentController : Controller
    {
        private Company_DBEntities3 db = new Company_DBEntities3();

        // GET: kies
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var keyBySecurityDepartments = db.KeyBySecurityDepartment.Include(s => s.Employee).ToList();
            var Employees = db.Employees.Where(q => q.retired == false).ToList();
            
            KeyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel keyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel = new KeyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel();
            keyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel.employee= employees;
            keyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel.KeyBySecurityDepartment = keyBySecurityDepartments;
            
            return View( keyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel );
        }
```

In my Razor view I have this:

```
@using Company.ViewModels;
@model KeyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Index</h2>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.employee)
    {
        @item.EmployeeNr
    }
</div>
```

I got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Company.Models.KeySecurtiyDepartment ]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Company.ViewModels.KeySecurtiyDepartmentViewModel'.

Comment: Can you show the whole view, pls?

Comment: Very obviously, that controller action is NOT the one rendering that view.

Comment: This is the Whole view I am testing, but it is not containing all elements since it is not working and I am still trying to fix it. I want to get the properties of the employee(EmployeeNr, Name, FirstName etc...) but also the key properties (like key number, door it can open, date when it can open etc...)

Comment: `@using Company.ViewModels;`
`@model IEnumerable<KeyBySecurityDepartmentViewModel>`
`@{`
   ` ViewBag.Title = "Index";`
    `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`
}
`<h2>Index</h2>`
`<p>`
   `@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")`
`</p>`
`<div>@foreach (var item in Model)`
 ` { <h4>@item.employee</h4>  }`
`</div>`
`<div>@foreach (var item in Model) {<h4>@item.keyBySecurityDepartment</h4>}`
`</div>`